# send multiple emails using Python

Tags: python

please help on below
i want send multiple receptionist email from outlook

below is my code

```
import win32com.client`import csv`with open('D:/python changes report/keshav/people.txt', 'r') as file:`reader = csv.reader(file)
distro = [row for row in reader]
print(distro)
#for row in reader:
    #print(row)enter code here
chunks = [distro[x:+100] for x  in range (0, len(distro), 100)]
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch('outlook.application')

for chunk in chunks:
    for email in chunk:
    message = outlook.CreateItem(0)
    message.TO = email
    message.Subject= "Test mail"
    message.Body = "if you received attachment then please reply"
    attachment1 = "D:/python changes report/keshav/output/DSR Tracker SMON.xlsx"
    attachment2 = "D:/python changes report/keshav/output/DSR Tracker REL.xlsx"
    message.Attachments.Add(attachment1)
    message.Attachments.Add(attachment2)
    message.Send()
```

but i got below error, please help to resolve

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
```

File "", line 4, in 
File "C:\Users\rupalim\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\dynamic.py", line 686, in **setattr**
self.*oleobj*.Invoke(entry.dispid, 0, invoke_type, 0, value)
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (4096, 'Microsoft Outlook', 'The object does not support this method.', None, 0, -2147352567), None)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you please format the code? We can do that, but it might not reproduce the issue which you are facing.

Comment: Does this help you?
[python-sending-outlook-email-from-different-address-using-pywin32](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24192252/python-sending-outlook-email-from-different-address-using-pywin32)

Comment: no , actually i dont get it. please help